# Can't see build in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm listed under **App Store Connect Users**.

It says...

> App Store Connect Users can use the TestFlight app to test all
>   available builds. They’ll also be notified when a new build is added
>   and can test builds before they’re approved by Beta App Review.

That sounds like me. Plus, that's what has worked for some time now. Except, now I can't see the latest build in TestFlight, even though I've deleted all the other builds.

I tried re-adding myself as a tester and now, next to my status, it says... **No Builds Available**.

I've tried adding myself as an individual tester to the build. The selector shows my name but I can't select myself. huh?

I've also tried bumping up the version and re-uploading.

wtf is with this garbage software?! Surely some people at Apple ought to be flipping burgers for a living instead of sapping my will to live.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted support and received the following...

> I understand you are facing a problem where a recently uploaded build
>   is not available in TestFlight.
>
> We have had reports of this behaviour and our engineering team are
>   working to resolve it as soon as possible.